# <select> change event doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have strange issue, I have created select tag in asp.net mvc:

```
<select class="target" id="citySelect">
    <option >Option 1</option>
    <option selected>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

And added query listener:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#citySelect').change(function () {
        alert(test);
    });

});
```

The problem is if I change select class on selectpicker (from bootstrap) it doesn't work:

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="citySelect">
    <option >Option 1</option>
    <option selected>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Whats wrong? Thx.

Comment: you need to close your $(document).ready(function () {  with  });  ---so that last line where you have "}" you need "   });  "

Comment: If adding the `);` solve your problem you should not edit the question to include it.

Comment: It didn't solve it, I make a mistake in description of problem. I clearly wrote that it works fine when select class is not "selectpicker", so mb I didn't missing ");" in my actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miss the ) in the end

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.selectpicker').change(function () {
    alert($(this));  
    $(".result").html($(this).val());
  });
}); // you miss the )
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker" id="citySelect">
<option >Option 1</option>
<option selected>Option 2</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: It is not it , I just missed it in description of problem. As I said, it WORKS well if <select> class is not a "selectpicker".

Comment: I updated the code above, you put '.selectpicker' in jQuery?

Comment: The code above works with '#citySelect' or '.selectpicker'

Comment: I see, thx. In my code it still doesn't work and I don't know why ( 
Mb it is bcs I include conflict js libraries, it is so strange

Comment: Are you select in jquery with class or id? If be with id maybe you have the same class in different components

Comment: I am selecting by id, I have 2 <select> with different id's. it works well in Django, but when I copied it in ASP.NET mvc nothing works